# Displaying annotations in grafana in a tabular form

Tags: events, plugins, grafana

I'm evaluating using Grafana as a front-end for displaying data from an IoT application. To give more context to the question, please notice we plan to develop a custom datasource for grafana and use the [simple json datasource plugin](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) to access it from grafana.

One importan requirement is to list events, such a device failures, in a tabular form (for example, the latest 10 events). We are planning to use annotations as a means for registering those events. However, we haven't found any way to display these events in grafana. We have only found a cryptic comment on the [table panel's documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/table_panel/):

> If you have annotations enabled in the dashboard you can have the
>   table show them. If you configure this mode then any queries you have
>   in the metrics tab will be ignored

Is there any plugin available to display annotations or should we consider developing one?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

No need to develop one.

Here is a quick recipe:

Go to the dashboard annotaions tab and add a new annotation.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBDvg.png)

Under Query group select Tags from the "Filter by" drop down list and add a tag for those annotations you want to show on the table and then click Add (For this example I defined the tag as comment).

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBEWj.png)

Make sure Enabled is checked out and Hidden is not. You'll see in a minute.

Add a table panel to your dashboard. Go to Edit and under the Options tab select Annotation from the "Table Transform" drop-down list.

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyXXM.png)

Now all your annotations with the comment Tag should display on the table

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYMWj.png)

[Step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFWZo.png)

Ta daaaaaa!

Comment: I am abit lost following these instruction on v7.3 ... does anybody know how to do this in this version?

Answer (score 0):

How to show all Grafana annotations in a list (using Grafana 8.5.5):

1. Add a new panel (in an existing or a new dashboard)
   [image]
2. Search for the "Annotation list" panel type on the right side:
   [image]
3. Increase limit and adjust other settings if necessary:
   [image]
4. Apply, and save dashboard.
   [image]

Simple if you know how, quite hidden if you don't :D Happy that I finally found it :D